# Table historic with all the authorizations ids checked update column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sql-update

I have this problem... I need save my table historic with all the authorizations ids checked, update the column authorization_origin_id and set the column refinancing_id with the refinancing id created. Example: I checked authorizations ids 2 and 3, so I create historic with two lines with authorization_origin_id 2 and 3 and the refinancing id will be 1. My code:

My view this it:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@refinancing) do |f| %>
      <div class="form-inputs">
        <%= f.hidden_field :employee_id, value: @employee.first.id %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :authorization, value: @authorization  %>
        <%= f.input :contract_number %>
      </div>

      <h3>Reserved value</h3>
      <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
          <th>Authorization id</th>
          <th>Contract number</th>
        </thead>
        <% @authorizations.each do |authorization| %>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><%= authorization.id %></td>
              <td><%= authorization.contract_number %></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        <% end %>
      </table>

      <div class="form-actions">
        <%= f.button :submit, "To Reserve" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Controller is this:

```
 def new
        if params[:authorization].present?
          @selected_ids = params[:authorization][:contract_number]
          @authorizations = Authorization.where("contract_number in (?)", @selected_ids)
          auth_params = params[:authorization]
          auth_params[:contract_number].zip(auth_params[:value_solve].reject(&:blank?)).each do |contract_number, value_solve|
              Authorization.where(contract_number: contract_number).update_all(value_solve: value_solve, situation: 2)
          end

          @authorizations.ids.each do |auth_id|
            @historic_refinancing = HistoricRefinancing.create
            @historic_refinancing = HistoricRefinancing.update_all(authorization_origin_id: auth_id)
          end

        end
        @employee = Employee.search_cpf(params[:search_employee_by_cpf])
        @refinancing = Refinancing.new

      end
```

Actually my table historic is wrong, authorization_origin_id take, just the last (just one ever =/) value checked and refinancing_id is null

Comment: Yep, it is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36874731/solve-query-sql-with-rails/36875135#36875135

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is it:

```
@historic_refinancing = HistoricRefinancing.where(authorization_origin_id: auth_id).update_all(authorization_origin_id: auth_id)
```

or simply this

```
@historic_refinancing = HistoricRefinancing.create(authorization_origin_id: auth_id)
```